# Arduino client hangs when trying to make a socket connection

Tags: sockets, arduino

I am working on a project that involves sockets in local network - I want to make a Java server (desktop application running on Windows) that will listen to and make connections with several clients - Arduino boards.

The problem is, code stucks while trying to make a connection. Here's the Java code:

```
monitorThread = new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            System.out.println("Creating socket...");
            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(4444);
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("Waiting for connection...");
                Socket client = server.accept();
                //NetworkManager.this.didConnect(client);
                System.out.println("Did establish connection");
                if (delegate != null) {
                    delegate.didConnect(client);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            System.out.print(exception);
        }
    });
    monitorThread.start();
```

and the Arduino code

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

IPAddress serverIp(192, 168, 1, 101);
int serverPort = 4444;

byte mac[] = {
  0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xEF
};
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 1, 178);

EthernetClient client;

void setup() {
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);

  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }

  delay(1000);
  // give the Ethernet shield a second to initialize:

  Serial.println("connecting...");

  if (client.connect(serverIp, serverPort)) {
    Serial.println("connected.");
  } else {
    Serial.println("connection failed.");
  }
}
```

What happens is both of those do not fail when trying to make a connection, but rather hang - Java server hangs on `Socket client = server.accept();`, but Arduino hangs as well - on `client.connect(serverIp, serverPort)`

Computer running Java server has a static IP (192.168.1.101).

I understand Java's `server.accept()` is a blocking call, so it will not proceed until a connection is made (what's why it runs in a separate thread), but what puzzles me is why Arduino hands as well.

Even if I try to connect to some other server IP and port - for example `64.233.187.99` (Google), it still hangs.

What am I doing wrong? Is there some additional setup that I haven't done? Can it have something to do with my network's settings?

Comment: `connect` is a blocking call as well... it might be unable to reach the server or waiting for a network timeout...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kindly try these steps and give it a try:

- Turn off firewall on Windows (Java Server)
- Check from another network connected pc that you can connect (telnet) to 192.168.1.101 on port 4444 (ie: telnet 192.168.1.101 4444)
- Change delay(1000) line to delay(5000) to give arduino ethernet shield more time to initialize

Also please post your loop code. I am using exactly the same code to communicate arduino to a java socket server. Your code seems fine; it might be firewall or something. Make sure you check out telnet connection from another machine.